# filling the contour in matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, contour, fill, colorbar

I have a contour and I need to fill the space in between. This here is the script I am using. I do not understand how to sort my [data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1kqkqiqa0602e22/Vemu-t2hk-3s.txt?dl=0) so that it fills correctly.

```
`from pylab import *
from matplotlib import *
import matplotlib as mpl
import os
from global_tools import *
path = os.getcwd()+"/"
mpl.rcParams['font.size'] = 14
mpl.rcParams['legend.fontsize'] = 'large'
mpl.rcParams['figure.titlesize'] = 'medium'
print("Plotting allowed range...")
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[9,9])
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('linear')
pylab.xlim([1e-15, 1e-13])
pylab.ylim([135, 315])
lst_limits = Read_Data_File(path+"Vemu-t2hk-3s.txt")
lst_V = [lst_limits[0][j] for j in range(len(lst_limits[0]))]
lst_dcp = [lst_limits[1][j] for j in range(len(lst_limits[1]))]
ax.plot(lst_V, lst_dcp, color='C1', lw=3, zorder=20)
ax.fill_between(lst_V, lst_dcp, edgecolor=None, facecolor='C2', zorder=0, alpha=0.2)
pylab.savefig("lrf_dcp.pdf", bbox_inches='tight', dpi=200)
plt.show()
plt.close()`
```

```
1.0000e-15 1.9811e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0000e-15 2.6953e+02 9.0000e+00
1.3706e-15 1.9800e+02 9.0000e+00
1.3706e-15 2.6959e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6503e-15 1.9792e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6503e-15 2.6964e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9024e-15 1.9785e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9024e-15 2.6968e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1444e-15 1.9778e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1445e-15 2.6972e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3821e-15 1.9771e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3828e-15 2.6975e+02 9.0000e+00
2.6183e-15 1.9764e+02 9.0000e+00
2.6204e-15 2.6979e+02 9.0000e+00
2.8537e-15 1.9757e+02 9.0000e+00
2.8593e-15 2.6982e+02 9.0000e+00
3.0878e-15 1.9750e+02 9.0000e+00
3.1007e-15 2.6985e+02 9.0000e+00
3.3194e-15 1.9744e+02 9.0000e+00
3.3455e-15 2.6988e+02 9.0000e+00
3.5463e-15 1.9737e+02 9.0000e+00
3.5943e-15 2.6991e+02 9.0000e+00
3.7660e-15 1.9731e+02 9.0000e+00
3.8476e-15 2.6994e+02 9.0000e+00
3.9760e-15 1.9725e+02 9.0000e+00
4.1059e-15 2.6996e+02 9.0000e+00
4.1744e-15 1.9720e+02 9.0000e+00
4.3604e-15 1.9714e+02 9.0000e+00
4.3694e-15 2.6999e+02 9.0000e+00
4.5346e-15 1.9710e+02 9.0000e+00
4.6386e-15 2.7001e+02 9.0000e+00
4.6991e-15 1.9705e+02 9.0000e+00
4.8579e-15 1.9701e+02 9.0000e+00
4.9136e-15 2.7004e+02 9.0000e+00
5.0158e-15 1.9697e+02 9.0000e+00
5.1783e-15 1.9692e+02 9.0000e+00
5.1950e-15 2.7006e+02 9.0000e+00
5.3508e-15 1.9688e+02 9.0000e+00
5.4829e-15 2.7007e+02 9.0000e+00
5.5382e-15 1.9683e+02 9.0000e+00
5.7438e-15 1.9678e+02 9.0000e+00
5.7780e-15 2.7009e+02 9.0000e+00
5.9698e-15 1.9672e+02 9.0000e+00
6.0809e-15 2.7011e+02 9.0000e+00
6.2172e-15 1.9666e+02 9.0000e+00
6.3923e-15 2.7012e+02 9.0000e+00
6.4859e-15 1.9659e+02 9.0000e+00
6.7131e-15 2.7013e+02 9.0000e+00
6.7752e-15 1.9652e+02 9.0000e+00
7.0444e-15 2.7014e+02 9.0000e+00
7.0840e-15 1.9645e+02 9.0000e+00
7.3874e-15 2.7014e+02 9.0000e+00
7.4115e-15 1.9637e+02 9.0000e+00
7.7433e-15 2.7014e+02 9.0000e+00
7.7566e-15 1.9628e+02 9.0000e+00
8.1135e-15 2.7014e+02 9.0000e+00
8.1184e-15 1.9620e+02 9.0000e+00
8.4960e-15 1.9611e+02 9.0000e+00
8.4992e-15 2.7014e+02 9.0000e+00
8.8876e-15 1.9601e+02 9.0000e+00
8.9017e-15 2.7012e+02 9.0000e+00
9.2910e-15 1.9592e+02 9.0000e+00
9.3221e-15 2.7011e+02 9.0000e+00
9.7029e-15 1.9582e+02 9.0000e+00
9.7611e-15 2.7009e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0119e-14 1.9573e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0219e-14 2.7006e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0534e-14 1.9563e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0696e-14 2.7002e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0944e-14 1.9554e+02 9.0000e+00
1.1191e-14 2.6998e+02 9.0000e+00
1.1343e-14 1.9545e+02 9.0000e+00
1.1700e-14 2.6992e+02 9.0000e+00
1.1730e-14 1.9537e+02 9.0000e+00
1.2102e-14 1.9528e+02 9.0000e+00
1.2222e-14 2.6987e+02 9.0000e+00
1.2464e-14 1.9521e+02 9.0000e+00
1.2751e-14 2.6980e+02 9.0000e+00
1.2819e-14 1.9513e+02 9.0000e+00
1.3176e-14 1.9506e+02 9.0000e+00
1.3281e-14 2.6973e+02 9.0000e+00
1.3544e-14 1.9498e+02 9.0000e+00
1.3806e-14 2.6965e+02 9.0000e+00
1.3933e-14 1.9491e+02 9.0000e+00
1.4321e-14 2.6956e+02 9.0000e+00
1.4355e-14 1.9483e+02 9.0000e+00
1.4816e-14 1.9474e+02 9.0000e+00
1.4821e-14 2.6948e+02 9.0000e+00
1.5304e-14 2.6939e+02 9.0000e+00
1.5325e-14 1.9465e+02 9.0000e+00
1.5772e-14 2.6929e+02 9.0000e+00
1.5886e-14 1.9455e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6227e-14 2.6919e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6499e-14 1.9444e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6676e-14 2.6909e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7125e-14 2.6898e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7163e-14 1.9432e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7582e-14 2.6886e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7874e-14 1.9421e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8052e-14 2.6873e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8540e-14 2.6859e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8624e-14 1.9408e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9047e-14 2.6844e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9402e-14 1.9396e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9572e-14 2.6827e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0111e-14 2.6810e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0196e-14 1.9383e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0659e-14 2.6792e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0991e-14 1.9371e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1210e-14 2.6772e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1757e-14 2.6753e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1775e-14 1.9359e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2294e-14 2.6733e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2535e-14 1.9348e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2819e-14 2.6713e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3266e-14 1.9338e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3331e-14 2.6693e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3830e-14 2.6673e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3968e-14 1.9328e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4321e-14 2.6653e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4646e-14 1.9319e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4808e-14 2.6631e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5298e-14 2.6609e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5316e-14 1.9311e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5797e-14 2.6586e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5997e-14 1.9303e+02 9.0000e+00
2.6307e-14 2.6562e+02 9.0000e+00
2.6711e-14 1.9296e+02 9.0000e+00
2.6832e-14 2.6536e+02 9.0000e+00
2.7369e-14 2.6510e+02 9.0000e+00
2.7481e-14 1.9289e+02 9.0000e+00
2.7914e-14 2.6482e+02 9.0000e+00
2.8329e-14 1.9281e+02 9.0000e+00
2.8458e-14 2.6455e+02 9.0000e+00
2.8993e-14 2.6428e+02 9.0000e+00
2.9271e-14 1.9274e+02 9.0000e+00
2.9509e-14 2.6401e+02 9.0000e+00
3.0001e-14 2.6376e+02 9.0000e+00
3.0320e-14 1.9266e+02 9.0000e+00
3.0465e-14 2.6352e+02 9.0000e+00
3.0906e-14 2.6330e+02 9.0000e+00
3.1329e-14 2.6308e+02 9.0000e+00
3.1480e-14 1.9259e+02 9.0000e+00
3.1747e-14 2.6286e+02 9.0000e+00
3.2174e-14 2.6264e+02 9.0000e+00
3.2623e-14 2.6240e+02 9.0000e+00
3.2754e-14 1.9251e+02 9.0000e+00
3.3105e-14 2.6215e+02 9.0000e+00
3.3624e-14 2.6188e+02 9.0000e+00
3.4141e-14 1.9243e+02 9.0000e+00
3.4180e-14 2.6159e+02 9.0000e+00
3.4767e-14 2.6129e+02 9.0000e+00
3.5374e-14 2.6097e+02 9.0000e+00
3.5636e-14 1.9236e+02 9.0000e+00
3.5987e-14 2.6066e+02 9.0000e+00
3.5987e-14 2.6066e+02 9.0000e+00
3.6591e-14 2.6035e+02 9.0000e+00
3.7172e-14 2.6005e+02 9.0000e+00
3.7236e-14 1.9229e+02 9.0000e+00
3.7721e-14 2.5976e+02 9.0000e+00
3.8232e-14 2.5950e+02 9.0000e+00
3.8706e-14 2.5925e+02 9.0000e+00
3.8934e-14 1.9223e+02 9.0000e+00
3.9149e-14 2.5901e+02 9.0000e+00
3.9570e-14 2.5878e+02 9.0000e+00
3.9982e-14 2.5855e+02 9.0000e+00
4.0397e-14 2.5831e+02 9.0000e+00
4.0724e-14 1.9218e+02 9.0000e+00
4.0826e-14 2.5806e+02 9.0000e+00
4.1280e-14 2.5778e+02 9.0000e+00
4.1763e-14 2.5749e+02 9.0000e+00
4.2277e-14 2.5718e+02 9.0000e+00
4.2601e-14 1.9215e+02 9.0000e+00
4.2821e-14 2.5685e+02 9.0000e+00
4.3391e-14 2.5650e+02 9.0000e+00
4.3982e-14 2.5614e+02 9.0000e+00
4.4553e-14 1.9212e+02 9.0000e+00
4.4586e-14 2.5578e+02 9.0000e+00
4.5194e-14 2.5541e+02 9.0000e+00
4.5798e-14 2.5505e+02 9.0000e+00
4.6388e-14 2.5469e+02 9.0000e+00
4.6568e-14 1.9211e+02 9.0000e+00
4.6956e-14 2.5435e+02 9.0000e+00
4.7494e-14 2.5403e+02 9.0000e+00
4.7999e-14 2.5373e+02 9.0000e+00
4.8466e-14 2.5345e+02 9.0000e+00
4.8626e-14 1.9212e+02 9.0000e+00
4.8898e-14 2.5318e+02 9.0000e+00
4.9300e-14 2.5293e+02 9.0000e+00
4.9679e-14 2.5269e+02 9.0000e+00
5.0044e-14 2.5245e+02 9.0000e+00
5.0409e-14 2.5221e+02 9.0000e+00
5.0705e-14 1.9214e+02 9.0000e+00
5.0783e-14 2.5196e+02 9.0000e+00
5.1177e-14 2.5170e+02 9.0000e+00
5.1600e-14 2.5141e+02 9.0000e+00
5.2056e-14 2.5111e+02 9.0000e+00
5.2549e-14 2.5079e+02 9.0000e+00
5.2779e-14 1.9219e+02 9.0000e+00
5.3080e-14 2.5046e+02 9.0000e+00
5.3648e-14 2.5010e+02 9.0000e+00
5.4250e-14 2.4974e+02 9.0000e+00
5.4820e-14 1.9225e+02 9.0000e+00
5.4882e-14 2.4936e+02 9.0000e+00
5.5539e-14 2.4898e+02 9.0000e+00
5.6214e-14 2.4859e+02 9.0000e+00
5.6805e-14 1.9233e+02 9.0000e+00
5.6901e-14 2.4821e+02 9.0000e+00
5.7593e-14 2.4782e+02 9.0000e+00
5.8278e-14 2.4744e+02 9.0000e+00
5.8714e-14 1.9243e+02 9.0000e+00
5.8950e-14 2.4708e+02 9.0000e+00
5.9596e-14 2.4672e+02 9.0000e+00
6.0209e-14 2.4639e+02 9.0000e+00
6.0539e-14 1.9255e+02 9.0000e+00
6.0781e-14 2.4608e+02 9.0000e+00
6.1308e-14 2.4580e+02 9.0000e+00
6.1789e-14 2.4553e+02 9.0000e+00
6.2229e-14 2.4529e+02 9.0000e+00
6.2281e-14 1.9268e+02 9.0000e+00
6.2636e-14 2.4506e+02 9.0000e+00
6.3023e-14 2.4483e+02 9.0000e+00
6.3403e-14 2.4460e+02 9.0000e+00
6.3789e-14 2.4437e+02 9.0000e+00
6.3951e-14 1.9284e+02 9.0000e+00
6.4193e-14 2.4411e+02 9.0000e+00
6.4622e-14 2.4384e+02 9.0000e+00
6.5082e-14 2.4354e+02 9.0000e+00
6.5563e-14 1.9301e+02 9.0000e+00
6.5573e-14 2.4322e+02 9.0000e+00
6.6093e-14 2.4288e+02 9.0000e+00
6.6637e-14 2.4252e+02 9.0000e+00
6.7132e-14 1.9320e+02 9.0000e+00
6.7201e-14 2.4215e+02 9.0000e+00
6.7780e-14 2.4177e+02 9.0000e+00
6.8369e-14 2.4138e+02 9.0000e+00
6.8670e-14 1.9341e+02 9.0000e+00
6.8965e-14 2.4099e+02 9.0000e+00
6.9564e-14 2.4059e+02 9.0000e+00
7.0165e-14 2.4020e+02 9.0000e+00
7.0177e-14 1.9363e+02 9.0000e+00
7.0767e-14 2.3980e+02 9.0000e+00
7.1369e-14 2.3940e+02 9.0000e+00
7.1647e-14 1.9385e+02 9.0000e+00
7.1969e-14 2.3900e+02 9.0000e+00
7.2567e-14 2.3860e+02 9.0000e+00
7.3066e-14 1.9408e+02 9.0000e+00
7.3161e-14 2.3821e+02 9.0000e+00
7.3749e-14 2.3781e+02 9.0000e+00
7.4330e-14 2.3742e+02 9.0000e+00
7.4418e-14 1.9431e+02 9.0000e+00
7.4899e-14 2.3704e+02 9.0000e+00
7.5453e-14 2.3667e+02 9.0000e+00
7.5691e-14 1.9453e+02 9.0000e+00
7.5989e-14 2.3631e+02 9.0000e+00
7.6502e-14 2.3596e+02 9.0000e+00
7.6882e-14 1.9475e+02 9.0000e+00
7.6989e-14 2.3563e+02 9.0000e+00
7.7449e-14 2.3531e+02 9.0000e+00
7.7881e-14 2.3502e+02 9.0000e+00
7.7996e-14 1.9497e+02 9.0000e+00
7.8287e-14 2.3474e+02 9.0000e+00
7.8672e-14 2.3448e+02 9.0000e+00
7.9039e-14 2.3422e+02 9.0000e+00
7.9052e-14 1.9518e+02 9.0000e+00
7.9052e-14 1.9518e+02 9.0000e+00
7.9396e-14 2.3398e+02 9.0000e+00
7.9752e-14 2.3373e+02 9.0000e+00
8.0072e-14 1.9541e+02 9.0000e+00
8.0113e-14 2.3348e+02 9.0000e+00
8.0486e-14 2.3322e+02 9.0000e+00
8.0877e-14 2.3295e+02 9.0000e+00
8.1084e-14 1.9564e+02 9.0000e+00
8.1291e-14 2.3266e+02 9.0000e+00
8.1728e-14 2.3235e+02 9.0000e+00
8.2110e-14 1.9589e+02 9.0000e+00
8.2190e-14 2.3203e+02 9.0000e+00
8.2673e-14 2.3168e+02 9.0000e+00
8.3165e-14 1.9617e+02 9.0000e+00
8.3176e-14 2.3133e+02 9.0000e+00
8.3693e-14 2.3096e+02 9.0000e+00
8.4220e-14 2.3057e+02 9.0000e+00
8.4255e-14 1.9646e+02 9.0000e+00
8.4755e-14 2.3019e+02 9.0000e+00
8.5292e-14 2.2979e+02 9.0000e+00
8.5378e-14 1.9678e+02 9.0000e+00
8.5829e-14 2.2940e+02 9.0000e+00
8.5829e-14 2.2940e+02 9.0000e+00
8.6365e-14 2.2900e+02 9.0000e+00
8.6521e-14 1.9712e+02 9.0000e+00
8.6897e-14 2.2860e+02 9.0000e+00
8.7426e-14 2.2820e+02 9.0000e+00
8.7670e-14 1.9748e+02 9.0000e+00
8.7950e-14 2.2780e+02 9.0000e+00
8.8469e-14 2.2740e+02 9.0000e+00
8.8808e-14 1.9785e+02 9.0000e+00
8.8982e-14 2.2700e+02 9.0000e+00
8.9491e-14 2.2660e+02 9.0000e+00
8.9920e-14 1.9823e+02 9.0000e+00
8.9994e-14 2.2620e+02 9.0000e+00
9.0490e-14 2.2580e+02 9.0000e+00
9.0981e-14 2.2540e+02 9.0000e+00
9.0992e-14 1.9862e+02 9.0000e+00
9.1466e-14 2.2500e+02 9.0000e+00
9.1944e-14 2.2460e+02 9.0000e+00
9.2015e-14 1.9901e+02 9.0000e+00
9.2416e-14 2.2420e+02 9.0000e+00
9.2881e-14 2.2380e+02 9.0000e+00
9.2983e-14 1.9940e+02 9.0000e+00
9.3339e-14 2.2340e+02 9.0000e+00
9.3790e-14 2.2300e+02 9.0000e+00
9.3892e-14 1.9979e+02 9.0000e+00
9.4233e-14 2.2260e+02 9.0000e+00
9.4669e-14 2.2220e+02 9.0000e+00
9.4740e-14 2.0018e+02 9.0000e+00
9.5097e-14 2.2180e+02 9.0000e+00
9.5516e-14 2.2140e+02 9.0000e+00
9.5525e-14 2.0056e+02 9.0000e+00
9.5926e-14 2.2100e+02 9.0000e+00
9.6245e-14 2.0093e+02 9.0000e+00
9.6327e-14 2.2060e+02 9.0000e+00
9.6717e-14 2.2021e+02 9.0000e+00
9.6902e-14 2.0128e+02 9.0000e+00
9.7095e-14 2.1982e+02 9.0000e+00
9.7459e-14 2.1944e+02 9.0000e+00
9.7494e-14 2.0162e+02 9.0000e+00
9.7806e-14 2.1906e+02 9.0000e+00
9.8024e-14 2.0194e+02 9.0000e+00
9.8136e-14 2.1870e+02 9.0000e+00
9.8445e-14 2.1836e+02 9.0000e+00
9.8496e-14 2.0223e+02 9.0000e+00
9.8732e-14 2.1803e+02 9.0000e+00
9.8917e-14 2.0250e+02 9.0000e+00
9.8998e-14 2.1772e+02 9.0000e+00
9.9244e-14 2.1744e+02 9.0000e+00
9.9296e-14 2.0275e+02 9.0000e+00
9.9474e-14 2.1718e+02 9.0000e+00
9.9644e-14 2.0299e+02 9.0000e+00
9.9691e-14 2.1692e+02 9.0000e+00
9.9902e-14 2.1668e+02 9.0000e+00
9.9973e-14 2.0322e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0011e-13 2.1644e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0030e-13 2.0345e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0033e-13 2.1620e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0056e-13 2.1595e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0062e-13 2.0369e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0079e-13 2.1569e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0095e-13 2.0394e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0105e-13 2.1541e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0129e-13 2.0421e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0131e-13 2.1511e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0159e-13 2.1479e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0164e-13 2.0451e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0187e-13 2.1445e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0200e-13 2.0482e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0215e-13 2.1410e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0235e-13 2.0515e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0242e-13 2.1374e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0269e-13 2.0550e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0269e-13 2.1336e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0295e-13 2.1298e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0300e-13 2.0587e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0320e-13 2.1259e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0329e-13 2.0624e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0342e-13 2.1219e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0355e-13 2.0662e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0362e-13 2.1180e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0377e-13 2.0701e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0381e-13 2.1140e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0395e-13 2.0741e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0396e-13 2.1100e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0409e-13 2.1060e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0410e-13 2.0780e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0419e-13 2.1020e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0420e-13 2.0820e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0426e-13 2.0980e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0427e-13 2.0860e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0430e-13 2.0940e+02 9.0000e+00
1.0430e-13 2.0900e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6059e-13 1.9700e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6061e-13 1.9740e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6061e-13 1.9660e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6066e-13 1.9780e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6066e-13 1.9620e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6074e-13 1.9580e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6075e-13 1.9820e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6085e-13 1.9540e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6088e-13 1.9860e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6099e-13 1.9500e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6105e-13 1.9900e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6116e-13 1.9460e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6127e-13 1.9940e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6135e-13 1.9420e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6153e-13 1.9980e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6157e-13 1.9380e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6180e-13 1.9340e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6185e-13 2.0020e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6206e-13 1.9300e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6222e-13 2.0060e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6234e-13 1.9260e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6264e-13 1.9220e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6264e-13 2.0100e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6296e-13 1.9180e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6313e-13 2.0140e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6330e-13 1.9140e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6365e-13 1.9100e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6368e-13 2.0180e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6402e-13 1.9060e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6430e-13 2.0220e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6441e-13 1.9020e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6481e-13 1.8980e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6499e-13 2.0260e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6522e-13 1.8940e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6565e-13 1.8900e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6576e-13 2.0300e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6609e-13 1.8860e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6654e-13 1.8820e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6661e-13 2.0340e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6701e-13 1.8780e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6749e-13 1.8740e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6755e-13 2.0380e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6797e-13 1.8700e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6847e-13 1.8660e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6859e-13 2.0420e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6859e-13 2.0420e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6898e-13 1.8620e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6950e-13 1.8580e+02 9.0000e+00
1.6972e-13 2.0460e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7002e-13 1.8540e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7056e-13 1.8500e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7097e-13 2.0500e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7110e-13 1.8460e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7165e-13 1.8420e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7221e-13 1.8380e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7232e-13 2.0540e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7278e-13 1.8340e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7335e-13 1.8300e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7378e-13 2.0579e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7393e-13 1.8260e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7452e-13 1.8220e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7511e-13 1.8180e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7536e-13 2.0619e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7571e-13 1.8140e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7631e-13 1.8100e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7692e-13 1.8060e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7704e-13 2.0658e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7753e-13 1.8020e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7815e-13 1.7980e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7877e-13 1.7940e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7883e-13 2.0696e+02 9.0000e+00
1.7940e-13 1.7900e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8003e-13 1.7860e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8067e-13 1.7820e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8070e-13 2.0734e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8131e-13 1.7780e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8195e-13 1.7740e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8259e-13 1.7700e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8264e-13 2.0770e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8324e-13 1.7660e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8389e-13 1.7620e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8455e-13 1.7580e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8461e-13 2.0804e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8521e-13 1.7540e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8587e-13 1.7500e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8653e-13 1.7460e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8660e-13 2.0836e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8719e-13 1.7420e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8786e-13 1.7380e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8853e-13 1.7340e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8857e-13 2.0864e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8919e-13 1.7300e+02 9.0000e+00
1.8986e-13 1.7260e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9048e-13 2.0889e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9052e-13 1.7220e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9119e-13 1.7180e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9184e-13 1.7140e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9231e-13 2.0909e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9250e-13 1.7100e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9315e-13 1.7060e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9380e-13 1.7021e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9402e-13 2.0924e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9443e-13 1.6982e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9506e-13 1.6944e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9561e-13 2.0933e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9567e-13 1.6907e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9629e-13 1.6871e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9692e-13 1.6838e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9706e-13 2.0936e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9758e-13 1.6806e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9831e-13 1.6776e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9837e-13 2.0933e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9916e-13 1.6749e+02 9.0000e+00
1.9955e-13 2.0924e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0019e-13 1.6723e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0062e-13 2.0909e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0146e-13 1.6699e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0160e-13 2.0889e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0252e-13 2.0864e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0303e-13 1.6676e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0340e-13 2.0836e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0426e-13 2.0804e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0495e-13 1.6653e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0511e-13 2.0770e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0596e-13 2.0734e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0682e-13 2.0696e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0724e-13 1.6629e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0724e-13 1.6629e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0769e-13 2.0658e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0856e-13 2.0619e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0945e-13 2.0579e+02 9.0000e+00
2.0991e-13 1.6604e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1034e-13 2.0540e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1124e-13 2.0500e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1214e-13 2.0460e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1291e-13 1.6577e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1304e-13 2.0420e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1394e-13 2.0380e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1485e-13 2.0340e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1575e-13 2.0300e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1619e-13 1.6549e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1667e-13 2.0260e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1758e-13 2.0220e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1849e-13 2.0180e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1941e-13 2.0140e+02 9.0000e+00
2.1966e-13 1.6519e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2033e-13 2.0100e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2125e-13 2.0060e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2218e-13 2.0020e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2311e-13 1.9980e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2322e-13 1.6487e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2404e-13 1.9940e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2498e-13 1.9900e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2592e-13 1.9860e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2677e-13 1.6455e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2686e-13 1.9820e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2780e-13 1.9780e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2875e-13 1.9740e+02 9.0000e+00
2.2971e-13 1.9700e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3022e-13 1.6423e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3067e-13 1.9660e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3163e-13 1.9620e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3260e-13 1.9580e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3349e-13 1.6392e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3357e-13 1.9540e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3456e-13 1.9500e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3554e-13 1.9460e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3651e-13 1.6363e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3653e-13 1.9420e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3753e-13 1.9380e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3853e-13 1.9340e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3925e-13 1.6336e+02 9.0000e+00
2.3954e-13 1.9300e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4056e-13 1.9260e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4157e-13 1.9221e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4168e-13 1.6312e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4258e-13 1.9182e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4357e-13 1.9144e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4380e-13 1.6293e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4454e-13 1.9107e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4548e-13 1.9071e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4560e-13 1.6278e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4637e-13 1.9037e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4710e-13 1.6269e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4720e-13 1.9004e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4796e-13 1.8975e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4833e-13 1.6266e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4864e-13 1.8947e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4924e-13 1.8921e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4932e-13 1.6269e+02 9.0000e+00
2.4975e-13 1.8896e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5010e-13 1.6278e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5018e-13 1.8872e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5055e-13 1.8849e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5071e-13 1.6293e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5084e-13 1.8825e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5110e-13 1.8800e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5117e-13 1.6313e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5131e-13 1.8773e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5149e-13 1.8744e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5154e-13 1.6337e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5166e-13 1.8714e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5181e-13 1.8681e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5182e-13 1.6365e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5195e-13 1.8647e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5205e-13 1.6397e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5209e-13 1.8612e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5223e-13 1.8575e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5225e-13 1.6431e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5236e-13 1.8537e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5242e-13 1.6467e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5248e-13 1.8498e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5258e-13 1.6504e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5261e-13 1.8459e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5273e-13 1.6542e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5273e-13 1.8419e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5285e-13 1.8380e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5287e-13 1.6581e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5296e-13 1.8340e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5300e-13 1.6621e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5307e-13 1.8300e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5312e-13 1.6660e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5318e-13 1.8260e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5324e-13 1.6700e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5328e-13 1.8220e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5336e-13 1.6740e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5338e-13 1.8180e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5346e-13 1.6780e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5347e-13 1.8140e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5356e-13 1.8100e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5356e-13 1.6820e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5364e-13 1.8060e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5364e-13 1.8060e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5365e-13 1.6860e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5372e-13 1.8020e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5374e-13 1.6900e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5379e-13 1.7980e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5382e-13 1.6940e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5386e-13 1.7940e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5389e-13 1.6980e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5392e-13 1.7900e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5396e-13 1.7020e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5398e-13 1.7860e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5402e-13 1.7060e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5404e-13 1.7820e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5407e-13 1.7100e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5409e-13 1.7780e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5412e-13 1.7140e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5413e-13 1.7740e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5416e-13 1.7180e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5417e-13 1.7700e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5420e-13 1.7220e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5420e-13 1.7660e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5423e-13 1.7260e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5423e-13 1.7620e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5425e-13 1.7300e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5425e-13 1.7580e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5427e-13 1.7340e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5427e-13 1.7540e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5428e-13 1.7380e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5428e-13 1.7500e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5428e-13 1.7420e+02 9.0000e+00
2.5428e-13 1.7460e+02 9.0000e+00
```

My data if it doesn't get attached

I tried arranging the data in both ascending and descending format of x range, still it does not work.[image: Attached is the figure I am getting now.] I want to fill within the contour (roughly within the orange lines) but as you notice the fill is spreading outside as well (light blue color). I do not need to draw the contour and fill it with different colors. I drew it like this so that I could make the question clear.

Comment: I'm afraid your plot is correct, given your data. Re your data, it follows a peculiar pattern. With ፨ representing a new line, the dat file contains the like of  `x0 y0a 9 ፨ x0 y0b 9 ፨ x1 y1a 9 ፨x1 y1b 9 ፨ ...` and one could think that there is a curve in even lines and a second one in odd lines.

Comment: @JohanC In unsorted data also not working, previously I had given unsorted data here.

Comment: @gboffi how does it need to be sorted for it to work? Maybe by the nearest neighbors? I do not have nay idea. I am stuck. These are basically x and y coordinates when z is all 9. So I need to plot and fill this contour when z =9 .

Comment: Didn't you notice the difference between `ax.fill` and `ax.fill_between`?  `ax.fill` needs the data in the order they are connected. `ax.fill_between` needs the x-data to be sorted (y data representing a curve), and will either fill *between* 2 curves, or between `y=0` and a curve in case only one curve is given.

Comment: @JohanC Yeah.. I missed it sorry! Yes, using ax.fill indeed improves the result a bit. However, still it is not correct. What else needs to be done?

Comment: Ok so now I am sorting my data as nearest neighbors and my problem got solved with ax.fill. Thanks! @JohanC